# Setup of DNS zone with secure zone updates

Tags: dns, bind

How do I run a `dns` server with a zone for a local domain and be able to add dynamic entries to the `dns` zone securely from selected hosts?

I have tried to setup a domain 'rag.local' with bind9. I have tried to add a new record to that zone using `TSIG`. It works now. The steps are below.

Used dnssec to generate secret key for the zone

```
$ dnssec-keygen -r /dev/urandom -a HMAC-MD5 -b 512 -n HOST rag.local
$ ls -l 
-rw------- 1 rag rag 118 Mar  7 23:22 Krag.local.+157+26937.key
-rw------- 1 rag rag 229 Mar  7 23:22 Krag.local.+157+26937.private
```

Copied .key to /etc/bind

```
/etc/bind$ ls -lt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root bind  265 Mar  7 23:43 rag.local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root bind  435 Mar  7 23:35 named.conf.local
-rw------- 1 root bind  118 Mar  7 23:33 Krag.local.+157+26937.key
```

named.conf.local

```
/etc/bind$ cat named.conf.local 

key "rag.local." {
  algorithm hmac-md5;
  secret "secret-key";
};

zone "rag.local" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/rag.local";
        allow-update { key "rag.local."; };
};
```

rag.local zone definition. EDIT: this file earlier did not have a valid name server and admin email for the zone. also the zone file missed an A record for the name server.

```
/etc/bind$ cat rag.local
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns.rag.local. admin.rag.local. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns.rag.local.
@   IN  A   127.0.0.1
ns  IN  A   127.0.0.1
@   IN  AAAA    ::1
```

You may get some error like below if zone file is not valid

```
Mar  8 00:00:44 rag-tos-laptop named[20349]: zone rag.local/IN: journal rollforward failed: no more
Mar  8 00:00:44 rag-tos-laptop named[20349]: zone rag.local/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

EDIT: after the zone file is corrected

```
Mar  8 00:23:43 rag-tos-laptop named[21469]: zone rag.local/IN: loaded serial 2
Mar  8 00:23:43 rag-tos-laptop named[21469]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
```

A sample nsupdate file

```
$ cat nsupdate.txt 
server localhost
debug yes
zone rag.local.
update add host1.rag.local. 3600 A 10.20.30.40
show
send
```

Ran update

```
 nsupdate -k Krag.local.+157+26937.private -v nsupdate.txt
```

Requires write permissions to `bind` group on `/etc/bind` to solve a few permissions issues.

Thanks

Comment: You want to be able to edit zone files on your DNS server from a remote host? Does `ssh` not cover that?

Comment: i would like some programs to automatically add SRV entries when they become available.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it:

dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-MD5 -b 128 -n HOST example.com.

editing conf. file:

```
// TSIG Key
key "example.com." {
algorithm hmac-md5;
secret "THE KEY GENERATED ABOVE"; 
};
zone "example.com" IN {
  type master;
  file "example.com.zone";
  allow-update{ key "example.com."; };
};
```

### This is the step that you have to add

give the named authorization to the /var/named folder:

```
# chown -R named:named /var/named
# find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
# find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

Note: after you have use nsupdate you need to reload the zone using this steps:

```
rndc freeze example.com

then reloading

rndc reload example.com  

then allowing dynamic updates again:

rndc thaw example.com
```

Comment: You could also use the `rndc-confgen` command and now you can also use harder to crack keys `rndc-confgen -A hmac-sha512`. The output of that command tells you where to put what.